# C++ Build warning in GCC ARM but not MS x86

Tags: c++, x86, constants, arm, airplay

I use the Airplay SDK which is a platform for building C++ apps for smartphones. It also has a x86 simulator which uses MS Visual C++ IDE + compiler.

Now, I have this class :

```
namespace Fair {

    class Bitmap : public Sprite {

    public:

        const CIw2DImage* const& getBitmapData() { return bitmapData; }; // warning: returning reference to temporary

    private:

        CIw2DImage* bitmapData;
    };

}
```

I get the above warning if I build with GCC (ARM) Debug. I don't get a warning with (x86) Debug.

I asked elsewhere and I got this reply :

> Because `const CIw2DImage* const' is a
>   const pointer to const CIw2DImage, and
>   Bitmap::bitmapData is a pointer to
>   non-const CIw2DImage compiler
>   automatically casts pointer to
>   non-const to const, so here's a
>   temporary. The following code might be
>   generated by a "typical" compiler:
>
> ```
> const CIw2DImage* const& getBitmapData() {
>     const CIw2DImage* const tmp = bitmapData;
>     return tmp;
> }
> ```
>
> Probably (x86) compiler doesn't detect
>   this problem.
>
> You might want to remove reference
>   symbol (&) from the prototype (why do
>   you want use a reference in this
>   case?)

If a compiler does that, then it's totally wrong practice..? Making the value returned more "strict" is simply at compiler-level, to prevent "abuse". (x86) doesn't detect because it doesn't "cause" the problem in the 1st case..?

I return a reference to a pointer for the sole reason to "save" 32 bits of memory, i.e. use the same block of memory as the bitmapData pointer but within a different context.

Any comments please?

Comment: Re: "I return a reference to a pointer for the sole reason to "save" 32 bits of memory" - a reference is (almost certainly) the same size as a pointer. It's usually more efficient to pass simple types by value.

Comment: When you pass a constant reference to a pointer, aren't you in fact passing the pointer itself? I.e no more memory is reserved for YAP (yet another pointer).

Comment: no, passing by reference passes by reference. Even if the reference is to a constant object, it's possible to use `const_cast` to change the object, so the indirection is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't save any memory at all returning a reference, it's just a pointer internally. In addition, const occurs completely at compile-time, there's no reason for any temporary to be produced- and even if it was, a const reference to it would be valid.

That code looks terrible to me personally but it's not undefined in any way.

Comment: 1) It's yet another pointer, or is it the original pointer itself? 2) No reason for temp, I agree, so it's a GCC bug? Wrongly produced code?

Comment: "const occurs completely at compile-time" - no, `T *` and `T const *` are two different types, so a reference to one can't refer to the other. That is why you need a temporary of the correct type for the reference.

Comment: "a const reference to it would be valid" - only within the scope of the temporary. It won't be valid after returning from the function.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is quite correct to do that. A reference must refer to an object of the correct type; here you have an object of type `CIw2DImage*`, and you need a reference to a different type, `const CIw2DImage*`. The only way to do this is to create a temporary of the correct type (which is possible here, since `const T*` can be implicitly converted to `T*`), and return a reference to that.

Unfortunately, that results in a reference to a temporary object in the scope of the function, which is no longer valid once the function returns.

The simplest solution is to return the pointer by value; this will be more efficient (as it avoids an unnecessary level of indirection), as well as avoiding this problem.

Comment: I still don't get it. The return value is const CIw2DImage* CONST, it's the SAME pointer but with added restrictions i.e can't change it at all. I still don't see a reason why a copy of it should be made anyway. I don't think the MS x86 would be so dumb as to allow this with no warnings, I suspect it simply optimizes it (as it should).

Comment: @Bill: no, the return type is `const CIw2DImage* const&`, a reference to a pointer. Even though it is a reference to a const type, C++ allows you to use `const_cast` to modify the object, so it really does have to be a reference. It can't be a reference to the class member, since that is a different type. MSVC must either be allowing the reference to refer to an object of incompatible type (which is nonconformant, but probably harmless), or silently returning a reference to a temporary (which is nasty).